# WCF chunk data with stream

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, chunking

HI,
I neet to pass chunk data from WCF service to client. I have a table with 16 million records, and so, when the client requests data from that table i open a datareader to that table and serialize and send every record to client,here is my method signature..

```
public AsyncResult FindAsync(AsyncRequest request)
```

where AsyncResult and AsyncRequest are MessageContract, and AsyncResult has a stream in it. the problem is that when a client call the metod my function does not returns untill all data is not writed in stream in server... is it possible to change this behavior or I have to use callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found great solution here
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/06/10/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution.aspx#6288340

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a [streaming transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx).  Check out the ["streaming" example at idesign.net](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations).  I believe it shows an example of what you want to do.