# cancel stream request from WCF server to client

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, streaming, chunking, chunks

I posted about stream request here 
[wcf-chunk-data-with-stream]:[WCF chunk data with stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853448/wcf-chunk-data-with-stream) 
 I solved that task but now when i close request in client part server continue to send data. is it possible to  cancel stream request from WCF server to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could Abort instead of closing proxy if you want to cancel. Make sure you handle the exceptions on the server side.

I usually do somehting like :

```
   serviceClient.Abort();
```